# I want to change the slugs of my terms dynamically

Tags: taxonomy, terms, slug

I'm looking to change my slugs dynamically so that they are displayed with the names of my terms, for that I created an option in the administrator panel that should allow me to start the process, but I do not really know where to start.

For starters I think I'll have to recover the taxonomies in which I find all the terms that I will have to dynamically change.

Would someone have a sample code that I could exploit for this function that i'm trying to create?

here are the taxonomies in which I will have to go to get my terms to modify these dynamically::

Taxonomies: recipe_category, recipe_type, recipe_event, product_category

here's the code that will allow me to start the process:

```
    <?php
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'slug_migrate_menu' );
function slug_migrate_menu() {
    add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=recipe', 'Migration des slugs', 'Migration des slugs', 'manage_options', 'slug-migrate', 'slug_migrate_page');
}
function slug_migrate_page() {
?>
<h1>Migration des slugs</h1>
<button id="migrateSlugBtn">Go !</button>
<div id="migrateSlugResult"></div>
<script>
jQuery('#migrateSlugBtn').click(function(e) {
    jQuery.post(
        '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
        {
            'action': 'slug_migrate',
        },
        function(response){
            jQuery('#migrateSlugResult').append(response);
        }
    );
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_slug_migrate', 'slug_migrate' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_slug_migrate', 'slug_migrate' );

function slug_migrate( $taxonomy ) {
    // Taxonomies : recipe_category, recipe_type, recipe_event, product_category
    // Pour chaque term des taxonomies : Effectuer un sanitize_title() du name du term et l'afficher


              // begin of code





              // end of code


        add_filter( 'editable_slug', 'sanitize_slug' );


    die();
}
```

PS: Here is what I have done for now, I do not know if it's a good reasoning, and any help would be welcome:

```
$terms = get_terms( $post->ID, $catslug);?>

          <?php foreach($terms as $term) : ?>

                <?php if($term->slug !== $term->name){

                    $find = array(
                        $term->slug
                    );

                    $replace = array(
                        $term->name
                    );

                    $replace = array_map( 'sanitize_title', $replace );

                    $permalink = str_replace( $find, $replace, $permalink );


                    echo $permalink;

                }?>

          <?php
            endforeach;
          ?>
```

Hi @chrisbergr

thank you for your help, I made a montage (image) of what I am trying to do (in fact, I would like to change the names of all of my terms dynamically, instead of having to do them manually):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got you right, the following code is all you need to solve this.

```
function my_function( $post_id ){
if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ){
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $my_args = array(
        'ID'        => $post_id,
        'post_name' => ''
    );
    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'my_function' );
    // update the post, which calls save_post again
    wp_update_post( $my_args );
    // re-hook this function
    add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function' );
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_function' );
```

See [wp_update_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) in the codex.

I just tested the code in WordPress 5.1 with the block editor.